# recursive function to remove '<' and '>' from array keys

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

I'm trying to get an xml file from an associative array having array keys encapsuled into '<' and '>'

I've tried to use a recursive function but it works correctly only on the first level:

Please remember my final goal is to create an xml, so any appropriate suggest is welcome

this is what I've done so far:

```
$arr = 
array('<Lev0_0>' => 0, 
      '<Lev0_1>' => 1, 
      '<Lev0_2>' => array (
          '<Lev1_0>' => 2,
          '<Lev1_1>' => 3
          )
);

print_r(RepairKeysMultidimensional($arr));

    function RepairKeysMultidimensional(array $array){
        $Keys = array();
        foreach($array as $Key => $Value){
            $NewKey = str_replace(array('<','>'),'',$Key);
            $array[$NewKey] = $Value;
            unset($array[$Key]);
            if(is_array($Value)){
                RepairKeysMultidimensional($Value);
            }
        }
        return $array;
    }
```

the output is:

```
Array (
[Lev0_0] => 0 
[Lev0_1] => 1 
[Lev0_2] => Array (
    [] => 2 
    [] => 3 
    )
)
```

Comment: what is the output from the above code?

Comment: @Akintunde007 just updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add affectation in your if statement:

```
function RepairKeysMultidimensional(array $array){
    $Keys = array();
    foreach($array as $Key => $Value){
        $NewKey = str_replace(array('<','>'),'',$Key);
        $array[$NewKey] = $Value;
        unset($array[$Key]);
        if (is_array($Value)) {
            $array[$NewKey] = RepairKeysMultidimensional($Value);
        }
    }
    return $array;
}
```

Comment: What a stupid error! Thanks (I'll accept as soon as possible)

Answer (score 3):

If that's the structure and you never expect `<` or `>` as part of the values, you don't need to loop over it just [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) it, strip out the chars and the [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) it back into an array.

```
<?php
$arr = array(
    '<Lev0_0>' => 0, 
    '<Lev0_1>' => 1, 
    '<Lev0_2>' => array (
        '<Lev1_0>' => 2,
        '<Lev1_1>' => 3
    )
);

$arr = json_decode(str_replace(array('<','>'), '', json_encode($arr)), true);

print_r($arr);
```

https://3v4l.org/2d7Hq

**Result:**

```
Array
(
    [Lev0_0] => 0
    [Lev0_1] => 1
    [Lev0_2] => Array
        (
            [Lev1_0] => 2
            [Lev1_1] => 3
        )

)
```

Comment: Thanks for showing another way: I think It's the best way to learn (+1)

Answer (score 1):

you are not affecting the result of the second call to the outer array!

Try this :

```
<?php
$arr = 
array('<Lev0_0>' => 0, 
  '<Lev0_1>' => 1, 
  '<Lev0_2>' => array (
      '<Lev1_0>' => 2,
      '<Lev1_1>' => 3
      )
);
echo str_replace(array('<','>'),'','<Lev0>');
echo '<br/><br/>';
print_r(RepairKeysMultidimensional($arr));

function RepairKeysMultidimensional(array $array){
    $Keys = array();
    foreach($array as $Key => $Value){
        $NewKey = str_replace(array('<','>'),'',$Key);

        unset($array[$Key]);
        if(is_array($Value)){
            $array[$NewKey] = RepairKeysMultidimensional($Value);
        }else{
            $array[$NewKey] = $Value;
        }
    }
    return $array;
}
```

The output of this is :

```
Array ( 
    [Lev0_0] => 0 
    [Lev0_1] => 1 
    [Lev0_2] => Array ( 
             [Lev1_0] => 2 
             [Lev1_1] => 3 ) )
```